# How should I choose parameters for a smaller-than-standard std::mersenne_twister_engine?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stl, mersenne-twister

I need a C++11 random number generator which is "good enough" and which I can save and restore state in. *I want the saved state to be significantly smaller* than the 6.6kb or so which this code produces

```
std::mt19937 rng (1);
std::ofstream save ("save.txt");
save << rng;
```

[std::mersenne_twister_engine](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/) has a large number of parameters. It's a bit scary.

For my purposes, a period on the order of billions is sufficient. I've heard of TinyMT, that may be appropriate but can't see how to implement it as a template specialization.

How should I choose the parameters? I suspect it will break badly if I merely reduce the "state size" parameter to a few words.

I would consider using a different engine entirely but, apart from tolerating a moderate period, I don't want to sacrifice the quality of statistical randomness. Artefacts such as the below (for linear congruentals) are unacceptable.

[image]

Comment: It might be simpler to just write a wrapper around TinyMT.

Comment: Consider [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) table if you are ok with a different engine. Also notice that your code saves the state of the engine in text mode, not binary. The binary size is just ~2.5kb.

Comment: Maybe, T.C., but I want to actually understand the issues. And sbabbi, 2.5kb is still too much, by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

If don't need a lot of numbers, any decent 64bit size RNG will be good. Out of top of my hat very good generator would be XorShift64*, paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6246, code https://github.com/Iwan-Zotow/xorshift64STAR

Another option to use is PCG,  "Quadratisch. Praktisch. Gut.", paper and code at http://www.pcg-random.org/

They are both statistically better than MT, the only disadvantage being small(er) period, but it is ok with you as far as I can see

Comment: Those are not necessarily statistically better than MT. Passing all of BigCrush does not tell everything. Matsumoto or L'Ecuyer have shown and explained that various times.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good generators with a small state: MRG32k3a, LFSR113, Chacha-8, Philox-32x4. Even Mixmax (with N=17) would be small by your standard (state of 17 doubles).

TinyMT is also a possibility, although Vigna has shown that some of the bits are not always good (not sure if the not so great lower bits really matters in practice).

I would be wary of xorshift based rngs, see the paper [Again, random numbers fall mainly in the planes: xorshift128+ generators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10020) by Matsumoto for example. I am also dubious of PCG, if only for the colored table on frontpage of the website: it dumbs things down too much, does not present all the relevant generators, and is skewed towards PCG of course.